# Find the residue of the function $f(z) = \frac{z^3}{(z-1)(z^4+2)}$ at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Problem: Calculate the residue of the function $f(z) = \frac{z^3}{(z-1)(z^4+2)}$ at $z=0$

I am confused on where to even start on this question since there is no pole at $z=0$. Is $z=0$ even a singularity of this function?

Comment: Suppose you were a mathematician in the early 19th century and you had defined the concept of a residue at the poles of meromorphic functions. How would you have generalized your definition in a consistent way such that it also applies to points where the function doesn't have a pole?

Comment: @CountIblis I am guessing your wanting me to notice that if a function $f$ doesn't have a pole at $z_0$, then the coefficient $a_{-1}$ in the Laurent expansion $f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_n(z - z_0)^n$ is always going to be zero?

Comment: That's right! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $0$ is *not* a singularity of $f$. Therefore, the residue at $0$ is $0$.